# How to click device Back button

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click device back button using selenium `Webdriver` + `AndroidDriver`
Below is the code which I am using:

```
((AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```

- gson 2.6.2
- Java client 5.0.1
- Selenium server standalone 3.6.0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
driver.navigate().back();
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this also, but it's not working at all.

Comment: Did You try to locate it by some kind of identifier (id, xpath) and store it inside element, and then try to click.

Comment: I have to click the device back button(Android device)so that I will navigate back to the application which I am automating. The application which I am automating is based on React-Native Technology, there is one functionality to call the saved contact. So when I click on the contact number of the user it is navigating me to the device's native Contacts application. After that, I have to click on the device back button, so that I will return back to the application which I am automating.

Answer (score 1):

```
Activity activity = new Activity("appPackageName", "appActivityName");
      activity.setAppWaitPackage("setWait");
      activity.setAppWaitActivity("setWait");
      activity.setStopApp(false);
      ((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivity(activity);
```

The above code worked for me.